# python histogram, looking messy and uneven

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataset, seaborn, histogram

I've a list of number the size of the list is "74004228" and the minimum value is "1" with maximum value "65852", I'm trying to get sense of how their distribution will look like, so I'm using plt.hist() to plot the histogram, but it doesn't give me anything.

I'm getting the following histogram which looks messy.
[image: histogram]

matplotlib code:

```
unique_values = sorted(set(dataset_length))
bin_edges = unique_values + [unique_values[-1] + 1]

plt.hist(dataset_length, bins=bin_edges, log=True)  # Align bins to the left
plt.title('Histogram of Data')
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

and I've tried

```
sns.displot(dataset_length)
```

the sns.distplot gives me an empty plot as below:
[image: sns plot]

any solution for this ?

Comment: It seems there are outliers in your data. You can remove those outliers by z-score technique. You can also take log of data and plot it. Log transformation normalizes the data.

Comment: I took the log of the data, it looks better but then I can not know the exact distribution for each index.

So what I did used dict to count the values 
'''
count_dataset_dict = {}
for item in dataset_length:
  if item in count_dataset_dict:
    count_dataset_dict[item] += 1
  else:
    count_dataset_dict[item] = 1
'''

then I took only the values with the threshold I wanted and then visualized it. now look much better

Comment: You might want to try functions such as `sns.stripplot(dataset_length)`, `sns.boxplot(dataset_length)`, `sns.swarmplot(dataset_length)` or `sns.boxenplot(dataset_length)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the log of the data, it looks better but then I can not know the exact distribution for each index.

So what I did: I used dict to count the values as follows

```
count_dataset_dict = {}
for item in dataset_length:
  if item in count_dataset_dict:
    count_dataset_dict[item] += 1
  else:
    count_dataset_dict[item] = 1
```

convert that to pandas DF and then filtered threshold of 1000

```
count_df_more_1K = count_df[count_df['count']>1000]
```

now I plotted the data

```
count_df_more_1K.sort_index().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(18, 8))
plt.title("Distribution of Index")
plt.xlabel("Index")
plt.ylabel("Count")
```

which looks something as follows

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cGy1.png)

Comment: This is what I said. "You can remove those outliers by z-score technique. You can also take log of data and plot it." You just removed outliers but based on your threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to consider is to take a random sample of your entire data, let's say 20% and then you can plot it just to get an idea of the Distribution.

Also, make sure you checked for any outliers in the data as it can skew your distribution.

It is just kind a hard to plot 7 million data points, with a range from 1 to 65K +